# Create stripe webhooks using API

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, stripe-connect

Is it possible to create `webhook` in stripe account using API if we have `client secret key` of destination account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>No, webhook endpoints can only be created, edited or removed via the dashboard, not via the API.</s>

EDIT: This is no longer true. Webhook endpoints can now be managed via the API: https://stripe.com/docs/api/webhook_endpoints.

If you want to receive events emitted from accounts that are connected to your platform, you need to set up a Connect webhook endpoint on the platform's account, not add endpoints to each connected account. See the documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#webhooks) for more information.

Comment: that is a shame, for developers creating integration with stripe it would be much nicer if setup only requires configuring the api credentials and we had a way to setup needed web hooks automatically. instead we have to provide additional setup details beyond our control whether the user completes them, and if they don't complete the needed setup we won't know about success or failure of subscription renewal. I am building a re-useable membership paywall solution for example and this makes it more complicated to setup correctly.

Comment: @JoeAudette You can now create and manage webhook endpoints via the API! https://stripe.com/docs/api/webhook_endpoints